# Extra HDD disk is not mounting when I start the machine unless I enter that disk from the GUI

Tags: mount, disk

When I turn the machine on I have a torrent program for example that saves data into this HDD disk and it says that the disk doesn't exist, If I go from the GUI to the disk and enter there then I go back to the torrent and now it's available to save the files.

I suspect that by entering to the disk through the GUI it mounts it and make it available from the rest of the session. It's weird that an eject button appears next to the disk

[image]

I don't know if this has anything to do but the gksu gedit /etc/fstab  is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=d5d25cbb-a5ab-4c28-92cd-3d1037563ec3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
#UUID=1672c5d6-df35-432a-b850-23a1b7886bc3 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=38a6a484-6730-4db3-aec9-76b294745e9b  none            swap    sw              0       0
```

How do I do to fix this and have the disk mounted by default at startup??. Thank you very much!

EDIT: Output of `cat /etc/mtab/`:

```
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3998528k,nr_inodes=999632,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=804048k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sdb4 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=737 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdb4 /var/lib/docker/aufs ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=804048k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
/home/ubuntu/.Private /home/ubuntu ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=8dfcf65b2176c5b6,ecryptfs_sig=c188bb8cce6b46dc,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu/Disco\040HDD fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

`sudo  blkid /dev/sda1` doesn't return anything.

```
 sudo lsblk /dev/sda1
 NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
 sda1 8:1 0 931.5G 0 part /media/ubuntu/Disco HDD
```

EDIT 2: it's strange

Output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT              LABEL
sdb           223.6G                         
├─sdb4 ext4   205.8G /                       
├─sdb2 ext4     2.7G                         
├─sdb3 swap     5.9G [SWAP]                  
└─sdb1 ntfs     100M                         
sda           931.5G                         
└─sda1 ntfs   931.5G /media/ubuntu/Disco HDD Disco HDD
```

is it ok that the HDD is outside the sdb? :S I used to have Windows with dual boot, what should I put as "mount point on the fstab file?, could you tell me what line should I add there?...the UUID is different as well, is not as long as the other disk id....

/dev/sda1: LABEL="Disco HDD" UUID="5ED2B771D2B74C51" TYPE="ntfs"

Comment: Mount the disk and then [edit] your post to include the output of `cat /etc/mtab`

Comment: Not related directly, but better not to use spaces with Linux. You have to either use quotes all the time or escape(\040)it like your entry: /media/ubuntu/Disco\040HDD. Better to use CamelCase, under_score, or just onename. Or use Disco_HDD or DiscoHDD. You can use Disks or gparted to change label.

Comment: thanks, it was a windows created partition, I changed the name to just HDD

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you posted the drive partition in question is `/dev/sda1`

To mount it at boot time, first determine the UUID by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issuing the command

`sudo blkid /dev/sda1`

Then edit /etc/fstab and follow the existing format:

UUID=*the UUID obtained in the previous step* <kbd>Tab</kbd>*mount point*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*fstype*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*any necessary options*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*dump*<kbd>Tab</kbd>*fsck*

Note: If for some unknown reason you get no output from `sudo blkid` you can simply use the device name instead. (In this case `/dev/sda1` instead of UUID=*I don't have one*) Be aware that using the device name in this fashion can result in mounting failures/irregularities if any drive is moved to a different physical port or removed.

All entries in italics need to be replaced with the necessary values for your situation.
For more detail on fstab see http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/fstab.htm

Comment: sudo  blkid /dev/sda1 doesn't return anything.....I'm on ubuntu 16.10

Comment: If the device is attached It should. You can go old school and use /dev/sda1 instead of the UUID=*uuid* field.

Comment: FYI `blkid` is part of this [essential package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/util-linux) and is included with 16.10 (yakkety)

Comment: it's plugged for sure...I'm using the disk now and itś not returning anything with that command

Comment: try `lsblk` then or review http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html

Comment: sudo  lsblk  /dev/sda1

NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/ubuntu/Disco HDD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50490/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-juan).

Comment: I forgot to use sudo, now I get this

sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Disco HDD" UUID="5ED2B771D2B74C51" TYPE="ntfs"

Comment: should I adda new line to the fstab or edit an existing one?. I don't know what to do now with that ID